# Print exceptions in a file

Tags: python

How to print only the exceptions `using python` that is present in a file /tmp/exceptions.log  ignoring all the debug statements.The snapshot of the exception is given below..

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/site/bank/views.py", line 1695, in importmydata
         o.save()
       File "/usr/site/cl/django/django/db/models/base.py", line 435, in save
         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)

     IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'option_b' cannot be null")
     2011-04-14 11:57:40,895 DEBUG In exception
     2011-04-14 11:57:40,915 DEBUG No resource found
     2011-04-14 11:57:40,926 DEBUG Name
     2011-04-14 11:57:40,915 DEBUG No resource found
     2011-04-14 11:57:40,915 DEBUG No resource found
     2011-04-14 11:57:40,915 DEBUG No resource found
     2011-04-14 11:57:40,915 DEBUG No resource found
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/site/bank/views.py", line 1695, in importmydata
         o.save()
       File "/usr/site/cl/django/django/db/models/base.py", line 435, in save
         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)

     IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'option_b' cannot be null")
     2011-04-14 11:57:40,895 DEBUG In exception
     2011-04-14 11:57:40,915 DEBUG No resource found
     2011-04-14 11:57:40,926 DEBUG Name
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use grep with exclusion flag , e.g.

```
grep -v DEBUG /tmp/exceptions.log
```

This will print the lines that **don't** contain the "DEBUG" string.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(\w+:\s.*\n)')
>>> pat.findall(c) # c is your logs content
['IntegrityError: (1048, "Column \'option_b\' cannot be null")\n', 'IntegrityError: (1048, "Column \'option_b\' cannot be null")\n']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use "logview", available in the PyPI.  If you look at the most recent version of my code for PyWorkbooks (here https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyworkbooks/), there is an easy_log file that sets up logging to the logview application.

logview is an excellent gui and allows you to do things like filter inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using try-except structure you can do something like:

```
try:
    foo()
except Exception,ex:
    print "Exception %s"%str(ex) # Output exception
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0] # Exception message
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc() # Output full traceback if you want one
```